# changing map side join to reduce side join got slight more data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Because Map side join is not able to split input file, so I changed to reduce side join for improving performance. Finally the performance got improved, but I got slight more data about one in a thousand. I've already dug many days but still not able to figure it out.
The map side join procedure as following: 
UserId(map key)==> ReportId(reduce key) ==> Output

The reduce side uses two emrs:
EMR1: UserId(Map Key)==>UserId(Reduce Key) This job for finishing the join by UserId
EMR2: UserId(Map Key)==> ReportId (ReduceKey) ==> output
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: How do you know about `more data`? Which counter did you look at?

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I looked at "Reducer input Group", I found more number than map-side-join. I mean the "Reducer input group" is the reducer-side-join second reduce.